# Smartgit not opening

Tags: git, smartgit

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I have installed a gui client `smartgit` for git via ppa, the `smartgit` icon even shows up in the dash home.

[image]

But on clicking the icon the program does not open and nothing happens , no error message is shown. Can anybody help me with why is that happening ?

Comment: Try launching it from a terminal. There might be useful output there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Step 1: Install OpenJDK 8**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

For more information how to install Java, take a look at [How To Install Java with Apt-Get on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)

**Step 2: Make version 8 your default Java**

Check which jdk versions are available on your system

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives --list
```

you should see something like:

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 1069 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Change default Java version:

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

**Step 3: Update SmartGit config**

Open smartgit.vmoptions

```
$ nano ~/.smartgit/smartgit.vmoptions
```

and add:

```
jre=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/
```

Comment: As soon as I switched to Java 1.8 from Java 1.7 smartgit worked!

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal where smartgit git is placed . 
Write

```
cd smartgit
cd bin
sh smartgit.sh
```

It will work .

Also if there are any java sdk related issues your screen will prompt with an error .

Comment: was doing `./smartgit.sh` . This `sh smargit.sh` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you edit the `SMARTGIT_JAVA_HOME` var in `smargit.sh` ?
It should point to your java install dir
Make sure you also have `git` installed

some tutorials [here](https://solaajayi.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/installing-smartgit-in-ubuntu-linux-10-04/) and [here](http://eric.sau.pe/how-to-install-smartgit-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

I had also the same issue , when I checked the JDK was been removed just installed it again, this resolved my issue 
`sudo apt-get install  openjdk*`